# Get all the buckets for a aggregate elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to get all the buckets available for a particular aggregate. Is there any query or endpoint to get the buckets?
Below is my Mapping. If I query with any filter then the related buckets are coming up, but I want all the buckets to show it on the frontend to have or operations.
Example: If we have 2 records, one is with category as chair and the other is in the table. If I select a chair it is returning table count is zero but it should show as table count as 1. So user can select both.

MyMapping:

```
{
"properties": {
  "australiasellable": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "avgRating": {
    "type": "float"
  },
  "categories": {
    "type": "nested"
  },
  "category": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "categorycode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "categoryname": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "colour": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "commercialuse": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "customisable": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "depth": {
    "type": "float"
  },
  "freedelivery": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "height": {
    "type": "float"
  },
  "listprice": {
    "type": "float"
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "geo_point"
  },
  "material": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "materialcode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "message": {
    "type": "geo_point"
  },
  "numberOfRating": {
    "type": "long"
  },
  "online": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "outdooruse": {
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  "productid": {
    "type": "long"
  },
  "productimageurl": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "productname": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "producttypecode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "sellercode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "sellerdescription": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "shortdescription": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "sku": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "state": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "stylecode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "warrantycode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fielddata": true
  },
  "weight": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "width": {
    "type": "float"
  }
}
```

}

Regards,
Sreenivas

Comment: please share your query and some sample docs and expected o/p which includes your buckets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be not to set the filter in the `query` section of your payload but rather perform [filtered aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation) and use the [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to get the `_source`s of the matched docs.

Long story short, if you apply a `query`, it'll of course affect your aggregations. So the trick is to not apply any query (either `match_all` or remove the whole `query` object) and perform the queries in the sub-aggregations as follows:

Using your `category` field:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "actual_query_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "category.keyword": {
            "value": "chair"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "actual_query_agg_top_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": [
              "category"
            ],
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "excluding_my_query_filtered_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "category.keyword": "chair"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_other_categories_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "categorized_other_docs_agg_top_hits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "_source": [
                  "category"
                ],
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can get rid of the `top_hits` sub-aggregations if you're just interested in the counts and not the underlying docs, i.e.:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "actual_query_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "category.keyword": {
            "value": "chair"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "excluding_my_query_filtered_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "category.keyword": "chair"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_other_categories_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```